# Add field to Django queryset

Tags: django, model, django-queryset

I'm working on a small project, with an existing database, filled with data. Every day we run a task to get a number of records and email the results. For one of the values we email, we need to perform a calculation (string replacement) on an existing field. We now do this using a model method. But to do this, we need to iterate over all the objects in the queryset.

How can I add/extend a calculated field to the queryset at the moment that we run the query? Note that this is not an existing field in the model, and that we have to perform some replacements on an existing field. Can I use a custom model manager for this? And if so, do you have an example?

The model method:

```
def get_application_dir(self):
    trails = {
        'xxx': '/abc/123',
        'yyy': '/xyz/789',
    }

    app = self.application
    file = self.filename

    if app in trails:
        traillen = len(trails[app])
        if file[-traillen:] == trails[app]:
            return file[:-traillen]

    return file
```

The use in the view:

```
if files:
    result['i'] = []
    for f in files:
        a = {
           'application_name': f.application_name,
           'directory': f.get_application_dir()
           }
        result['i'].append(a)
```

So, I don't want to perform the loop above, by just getting the value/field from the ORM. Is this possible? Maybe by creating a custom model manager, and extending the queryset?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is not something that can be done in the database level, you will iterate the queryset in any case. Don't you iterate it anyway to construct the email body?

Comment: Hi @Selcuk, thanks for the quick reply. No I'm not. But what I am doing, is casting it to a (value) list. Can't I just extend the queryset, by modifying the model's manager?

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your code and the expected result?

Comment: I posted the relevant pieces of code. @Selcuk